# NSCoding doesn't seem to store the frame of my UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, nscoding

I can't seem to get NSCoding to store the 'frame' or 'center' properties of my UIImageView subclassed object.  It seems to store everything else, both custom properties and standard class properties (e.g. 'hidden', etc...), but not the 'frame' or 'center' properties.  I'm NOT trying to archive a UIImage (as this does not comply with NSCoding).

I will post code if needed but I'm not doing anything special to the 'frame' other than setting it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame is based on the parents coordinate system and there is no parent until you add the view. If you have a subclass you could override the coding methods and store the frame yourself, although it might not end up being in the right position based on the parent view.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the quick response.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could store that frame as a string using NSStringFromCGRect() and then read it back later using CGRectFromString(). However, it is all based on the parent view frame so just keep that in mind.